# Issue migrating mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a legacy php project that I need to convert from mysql to mysqli. 
The conversion seems quite straight forward except for one part.

In mysql the following code seems to work well:

```
$query = "select c.id from contact c";
$queryResult =  mysql_query($query);
$result = mysql_result($queryResult,0,"c.id");
```

I am translating the code to:

```
$connection = new mysqli(...)
$queryResult = $connection->query($query);
$queryResult->data_seek(0);
$result_row = $queryResult->fetch_assoc();
$result = $result_row["c.id"];
```

However it seems that in mysqli "c.id" is not valid. I need to use "id".
I been looking at mysql to mysqli conversion posts but I haven't seen any solution to this particular issue. I know I can update the query to use something like

```
"select c.id as cid from contacts"
```

However there are hundreds of queries that I need to manually convert so I was wondering if there is any easy way of getting the "c.id" part to work with mysqli.

Thanks.

Comment: What field names does your `$result_row` contain instead?

Comment: If *id* is a unique name, you can use just `$result_row['id']`... Otherwise, it's better to create aliases for all repeated fields.

Comment: According to the manual, you can access the 'fields' as objects with quite a lot of information about them. I haven't tested this. It may be useful. [mysqli-result.fetch-field](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php). 'Mysqli result' is quite an 'interesting' structure rather than just a simple array: [class.mysqli-result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)

Comment: If you do 'fetch_fields' and 'var_dump' them. You can easily see how to get the 'alias' information that you require. I suspect that 'automating the conversion' may be not as much work as it first appears.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I think you are right. If the field has a dot I can use the information from fetch_fields to match the field to the appropiate column.